# How integrate pull request Azure Devops Repository With Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops, jenkins-plugins, devops, pull-request

I have a Git repository on the Azure Dev-ops server and use Jenkins for continuous integration build.
I want to know that how a specific branch like master Jenkins can automatically run the build and then notify the user via a shell log that the build was successful or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft seems to have the thing pretty well documented, [Create a service hook for Azure DevOps Services and TFS with Jenkins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/jenkins?view=azure-devops)

Set up the Jenkins job, set up the TFS / Azure DrevOps ServiceHook, off to the races.

We have it working fine for Jenkins 2.x and AzureDevOps on-prem. Best to use service accounts with limited necessary permissions on both sides.